# How to select cells with text?

Tags: qgis, python, select-by-attribute, text

I have point layer with text field. There is many empty field. I want to select only filled text. Something like this, with QGIS:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Maybe something like: `"Text" IS NOT NONE`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use that same expression `"text" = ""` and then use "invert feature selection" (this option is under the down arrow on the right side of `select features using a expression`)

also, `"text" != ""` should work too